# com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-appbarlayout

putting an EditText in an AppBarLayout is throwing an exception.
Here my layout.

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_included"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        app:adSize="BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="@string/adUnitIdTest_Banner"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="noScroll" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:hint="@string/title_hint"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:fontFamily="@font/raleway_regular" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

I am getting the following exception when starting the activity:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
```

viewBiding is true.
I don't know which MaterialTextView the exception is referring to.

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityWorkoutBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
```

The line `binding = ActivityWorkoutBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)` is throwing the exception.

Best regards

Comment: Did you used MaterialTextView earlier and then changed to EditText later? If yes can you try to clean and rebuild again, because there is sometimes a problem with the cached build data.

Comment: I was using a TextView in the activity code without knowing. Since I have corrected it to use EditText, I am getting the exception. Cleaning and rebuilding the project has no effect.

Comment: can you share your java code? it will help to understand the issue better

Comment: do you even used MaterialTextView anywhere is project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out. The AppBarLayout seems to have a built in TextView with the id `title`. I changed the id from my EditText from `title` to something else and it worked.